# XML Mapping : lost

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, feed

hello all (please excuse my profanity in advance as I am not really skilled on those topics but trying to learn)

I'm stuck on something that should be simple :

I have an input a basic cfm file with pictures tags looking like this :

```html
<Attachments>
<Image1>
<URL>
<![CDATA[
http://url.com/BO_files/20161110152752.jpg
]]>
</URL>
</Image1>
<Image2>
<URL>
<![CDATA[
http://url.com/20161110152747.jpg
]]>
</URL>
</Image2>
```

And a mapping file to pull them that says

```html
 <attachments>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Attachments/Image/URL">
                            <image><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></image>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </attachments>
```

however though it looks like it doesn't go through & I can't find a way to map it in a way that will say Take picture 1, then Picture 2, then 3, etc..

Any idea ? Thks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Image` element in the shown input, so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Attachments/Image/URL">
```

selects nothing. Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Attachments/*/URL">
```

instead.